# Node program with oriento does not exit after select

Tags: node.js, promise, orientdb, bluebird, oriento

From within node.js I use the oriento module to access a OrientDB. In principle everything works fine, the only thing is the program dos not exit as it should. Here is the example:

```
const oriento = require("oriento");
const server = oriento({});
const db = server.use(dbname);
db.select("@rid").from("codelists").limit(1).scalar().then(function (result) {
    console.dir(result);
}).finally(function () {
    db.close();
    server.close();
    console.info("finished");
});
```

The programm executes the select, then the "then" and finally the "finally" clauses. All fine. But it does not exit. There seems to be something hanging on the event loop. But what? And how can I get rid of it? The problem actually is worse then just "press Ctrl-C" or have a process.exit() when everything is done, because the code is supposed to run within a unit test, where I cannot call exit. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is nothing bluebird or promises can do here for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved in the current master version of oriento. https://github.com/codemix/oriento/issues/170

Answer (score 0):

You can use `process._getActiveRequests()` and `process._getActiveHandles()` to see what's holding the app open. They are undocumented but commonly used in this scenario.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I can see the active requests and the active handles. But it is hard to make more out of this.